# Cocoa error 3840 - NSJSONSerialization parsing error with a single quote

Tags: json, xcode4.6

I am using Xcode 4.6. I get a valid Json string from the server with a single quote properly escaped. If I remove the single quote from the field on the server, I don't get any error.

Here is the json string:

```
jsonStr: '{ "status": 0, "message": "success", "object": [ { "currentthreatlevelname": "Guarded", "devicename": "Virendra\'s Pad", "threatlevelname": null, "enabled": false, "practicemode": false, "locationname": null, "currentthreatlevel": 3, "status": 0, "deviceid": "APLFC8C49AF-D4DF-4AE0-9E7B-D2A3E94ED387", "threatlevel": null, "location": null } ], "site": "s2 security" }'
```

produced by

```
NSString* jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here is the parsing code is:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: _receivedData
              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                error:&jsonError];
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are the opening and closing single quotes part of `_receivedData`?

Answer (score 2):

Escaping the single quote in "Virendra\'s Pad" makes the JSON invalid. Try removing the backslash.

Comment: what if we don't have control over the server, how to handle it on the client side?

Comment: You can sanitize the string before deserialization. Or, tell those that do control the server that they're sending invalid JSON.